# How to use Font Awesome 5 Duotone Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to apply Font Awesome 5 Duotone font family to my Xamarin Forms app but when launching it, icon is not displaying as it should...

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="fa-light-300.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Pro" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Font Awesome 5 Pro" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Fonts/fa-light-300.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Pro" />
</OnPlatform>

<OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeDuotoneFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="fa-duotone-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Duotone" />
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Font Awesome 5 Pro Duotone Solid" />
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/Fonts/fa-duotone-900.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Duotone" />
</OnPlatform>
```

In the code, FontAwesome Light works as expected. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you given the correct path and are you using the correct keys? Also, make sure you have configured it correctly as well!

Comment: I just think Im doing something wrong with the unicodes. Duotone has 2 layers, and I dont know how to use them in XamarinForms. Combining between Light and Regular I'm able

Comment: Tried looking for an implementation for Fontawesome with Duotone and i think i have found something useful can you see if this works for you: https://gist.github.com/tomh4/e3a37f1abba2361ed02c09577dc2f09c

Comment: Duotone icons contain two layers. You can follow [this link](https://gist.github.com/tomh4/e3a37f1abba2361ed02c09577dc2f09c) to implement DuoTone.